# Remove Rows with Non-Numeric Characters in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I am working with the below dataframe:

```
data_frame = data.frame(col1 = c("a","b","a","a","e") ,
                    col2 = c("",2,"dd",4,5))
```

Then I try to apply some filters:

> df_1<-data_frame[data_frame$col2!="",]

This filter works fine and returns with a data frame that has removed blank values in col2.

> df_1<-data_frame[(df_1$col1=="a"),]

This filter, however, is not returning a data frame that shows only "a" in column 1.

Also, my final goal here is to get a df which shows only "a" in col1 and numerical values in col2.

May I know how should I go about it? Thanks a lot guys.

Update:

Hi all, I tried the below code and it seems to be okay:

> d2<-data_frame[data_frame$col1=="a"&data_frame$col2!="",]

May I know, if I would like to add one more condition, which is to filter out non-numerical values in col 2, how should I write it? Thank you sooo much.

Update 2:

I tried this line but no luck..

> d3<-data_frame[!as.numeric(d2$col2),]

Update 3:

> d1<-data_frame[data_frame$col1=="a"&data_frame$col2!=""&is.numeric(data_frame$col2),]

I tried to add the last filter to filter out non numerical values based on col 2 in the original df and it returns with 0 rows.

Comment: It should be `data_frame[data_frame$col1=="a",]` not `data_frame[(df_1$col1=="a"),]`.

Comment: thanks Ritchie, I tried your suggestion and it still shows values other than "a".  Is there any operator I need to add if I am adding more than one filter? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Once you create `df_1` as a modified version of `data_frame`, you need to consistently use it. `df_1<-df_1[(df_1$col1=="a"),]`. What you have mixes `df_1` and `data_framw`: `df_1<-data_frame[(df_1$col1=="a"),]` is using the row numbers from `df_1` that are equal to `"a"`, but you are using those `df_1` row numbers in the original `data_frame`, and they do not correspond becuase `data_frame` has more rows than `df_1`.

Comment: You can combine as many conidtions as you'd like with `&` (AND)` or `|` (OR). My favorite way to filter out non-numeric values is to convert the column to `numeric` class and drop everything that ends up a missing value `NA`. So it would do that as a separate 2 steps: `df2$col2 <- as.numeric(df2$col2)` and then `df2 <- df2[!is.na(df2$col2), ]`. But you could go all at once, `df3 <- data_frame[!is.na(as.numeric(data_frame$col2)), ]`. Once again, be consistent in what data frame you're working with, in your question you mix `data_frame` and `d2`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Let me try again.

Comment: Thanks Gregor and Ritchie. It works now. Thanks sooo much for helping.